# How to learn Silverlight fast?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to make Silverlight application. I'm going to need server side, which I'm going to make with C#. What could be best way to learn to make simple application with Silverlight + C#? Here are few questions that I need to know... Btw. I have Visual Studio 2008 Pro and MS Expression Studio 3.

1) How can I make objects in silverlight?
2) How can I program actions/user inetractions?
3) How can I connect to server side with silverlight?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297001/picking-up-silverlight

Comment: possible duplicate of [Picking up Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297001/picking-up-silverlight)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a starting point, have a look at the many resources available on http://silverlight.net, e.g [videos](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/), [quickstarts](http://silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/) and so on.

Also check out the [reference documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838158(VS.95,classic).aspx), it also has a getting started section.

Comment: And if you're really in a hurry, then you should download the videos and play them in a video player with 1.5x speed :-)

Answer (score 7):

I would try this: [Getting Started with Silverlight Dev by Tim Heuer](http://timheuer.com/blog/articles/getting-started-with-silverlight-development.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great set that walks you through creating an entire app by Scott Guthrie.  I think the below link to a set of articles gives a great overview of how to use xaml, binding, layout, etc in Silverlight.  A great place to start because it gives you a feeling for what you can do in a somewhat practical application and you should be able to get through them rather quickly.

[Silverlight End To End Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-2-end-to-end-tutorial-building-a-digg-search-client.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight book from Manning: "Hello! Silverlight". Hello! Silverlight is a fast-paced, entertaining introduction to Silverlight. Authors Bill Reiss and Dave Campbell guide you hands-on from your first Hello World example through the techniques you'll use to add life to your web applications.

You can download it as PDF at manning.com:
http://manning.com/reiss/

Answer (score 2):

I would go to Brad Abrams Blog and follow his 16 some part tutorial. By the time you are done with that you will have a pretty good grasp on interacting with a server.

[Brad Abrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/03/17/mix09-building-amazing-business-applications-with-silverlight-3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You will find very easy to understable examples of silverlight at [Silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html).