# Advice About Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I'm `.Net Developer`. 
Now I want to learn `Silverlight`.
Please Provide some guidance for how can learn ?
Which book or site I would prefer ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966460/how-to-learn-silverlight-4-0

Answer (score 2):

I learned by diving in and building an application, along with a book (Pro Silverlight 2 in C# 2008 by MacDonald) and lots of googling, watching videos, www.silverlight.net, and some help from Stack Overflow.

But I guess it really depends on how you learn best, and what you want to do with it.

The basics of it come down to knowing XAML, Blend (maybe), and how to build services.

As a starting point, have a look at the many resources available on http://silverlight.net, e.g [videos](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/), [quickstarts](http://silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/) and so on.

Also check out the [reference documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838158(VS.95,classic).aspx), it also has a getting started section.

Ref :- [How to learn Silverlight fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527691/how-to-learn-silverlight-fast)

Comment: Please check above link and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I check all link..I think its a good for me.thanks to all.

Comment: If you like this answer then please marked it.